# Specializing a template method with enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I'm writing a template class that stores a `std::function` in order to call it later. Here is the simplifed code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    void call(T type)
    {
        function(type);
    }
    std::function<void(T)> function;
};
```

The problem is that this template does not compile for the `void` type because

```
void call(void type)
```

becomes undefined.

Specializing it for the `void` type doesn't alleviate the problem because

```
template <>
void Test<void>::call(void)
{
    function();
}
```

is still incompatible with the declaration of `call(T Type)`.

So, using the new features of C++ 11, I tried `std::enable_if`:

```
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<T>, void> call()
{
    function();
}

typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>, void> call(T type)
{
    function(type);
}
```

but it does not compile with Visual Studio:

> error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if'

How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: SFINAE works only for *deduced* template parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE doesn't work over (only) the template parameters of the class/structs.

Works over template methods whit conditions involving template parameters of the method.

So you have to write

```
   template <typename U = T>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<U>::value> call()
    { function(); }

   template <typename U = T>
   std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<U>::value> call(T type)
    { function(type); }
```

or, if you want to be sure that `U` is `T`

```
   template <typename U = T>
   std::enable_if_t<   std::is_same<U, T>::value
                    && std::is_void<U>::value> call()
    { function(); }

   template <typename U = T>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, T>::value
                    && !std::is_void<U>::value> call(T type)
    { function(type); }
```

p.s.: `std::enable_if_t` is a type so doesn't require `typename` before.

p.s.2: you tagged C++11 but your example use `std::enable_if_t`, that is C++14, and `std::is_void_v`, that is C++17

Comment: I didn't fully understand the subtlety that explains why SFINAE works in your case and not mine, but your code compiles. And thank you for your additional comments.

Comment: For production-level code, you probably also want a `std::is_same_v<T, U>` inside the `enable_if_t` to thwart an explicit `call<U>()` for `U` unequal to `T` from compiling.

Answer (score 4):

Specialize the whole class:

```
template <>
struct Test<void>
{
    void call()
    {
        function();
    }
    std::function<void()> function;
};
```

Comment: Sure it works, but the idea was to precisely avoid specializing the whole class by using recent SFINAE constructs.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't stick to use `void`, and your intention is to actually able to use `Test` without any parameters, then use variadic template:

```
template <typename ...T>
struct Test
{
    void call(T ...type)
    {
        function(type...);
    }
    std::function<void(T...)> function;
};
```

This way, you can have any number of parameters. If you want to have no parameters, use this:

```
Test<> t;
t.call();
```

So this is not exactly the syntax you wanted, but there is no need for specialization, and this solution is more flexible, because supports any number of parameters.

Comment: I gave a simplified version of the code, but actually the idea was to handle a void return type. I handled the input parameters with a variadic template as you suggested.